Can I copyright my game before trademarking?
I recently finished developing my first video game, and I'm trying to figure out what the next step should be. I almost got caught up in patenting it, but I went back after realizing that a patent is only used to protect a novel mechanic in the video game, not the whole game itself.
At this point, I'm looking at getting copyright and trademark protection for my video game. I understand that trademarks are used for logos and video game names (e.g. _Galaga_™ or _Galaga_®, with the symbols at the bottom right corners— traditionally). I also understand that I can use the ™ symbol if I have not registered the trademark. However, does this mean I can copyright the video game first and have it appear as an unregistered trademark? Or should I register for a trademark first before getting it copyrighted?
I would appreciate any answer to this question.

What jurisdiction are you operating in? In many places, you don't "copyright" a game — copyright is automatic for any creative work. So you already own the copyright for your game's code, assets, and writing, purely by virtue of creating them yourself. I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, but it might be worth editing your question to elaborate on where you're doing business and what you're trying to accomplish with respect to your intellectual property protections.

Well, currently I don't have anything copyrighted or trademarked. I'm only a freelance developer, so I don't even have a company yet.

As to what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm trying to create a marketable game that cannot be replicated without the developer paying me a fee. Of course, I know people can make clones, but that is another thing I'm trying to figure out.

Where I am, we have an automatic copyright on everything we create, as individuals (you do not need to be a company to be an author). However, we can register our copyright with the goverment which creates precedent which is useful in case of a legal dispute. And to register a video game here is a mess, because the concept of a video game does not exist in the law, so we have to register the copyright of the individual works (music, story, pictures, etc). And you don't trademark the game, you trademark the brand (logo and identifiers). But it changes by jurisdiction, ask a lawyer.

I know about the logo, but what identifiers would I be trademarking? Characters?

With respect to video games, in the US trademark protects names, logos and slogans. I strongly recommend watching Practical IP Law for Indie Developers 301: Plain Scary Edition, which covers a lot of this. You can find it YouTube or at the GDC vault. Starts with copyright, trademark is about 12 minutes in.

Copyright protects many creative work aspects of your game including things like: music, writing, art and code. In the US the entire game is also protected by copyright as an audio visual work.
You are granted copyright by creating the work. Conversely, you cannot copyright something before it exists. You can preregister but preregistration is not a form of registration - it's simply an indication of an intent to register later on.  If multiple people are working on the project, you would need to sort out the copyright specifics with contracts.
Copyright does not protect abstract ideas, genres or game mechanics. You cannot prevent clones in the sense of someone making a similar game that plays in a similar way.
Trademark identifies goods and services as belonging to a business. It becomes active when you sell your game. In the US, trademark can either be registered (denoted with the ® symbol) or unregistered (denoted by the ™ symbol). It's subject to a first come first serve rule, but you can register for it before you get it to reserve your rights. Generally speaking registered trademarks offer stronger protections than unregistered trademarks. Again, if multiple people are involved, you may need contracts to clarify who holds the trademark rights.
So applying them to your question: you get copyright automatically by creating your works (assuming you're not under a contract that grants the copyright to someone else), but not before that. This differs from trademark because copyright is triggered by creation.
At the early stages of development, your early work has copyrights because at that point it's created. If someone were to use the same or similar work, you could go after them for infringing, but only for that part. If you have parts that you intend to make, but have not done any work on then none of that intended future work is protected because it hasn't been created. Put another way, if you cannot demonstrate that you've made something before someone else, you can't sue them for copyright infringement. It's meant to keep other people from profiting from work you've done. To protect concepts before they are developed into creative works, either keep them secret or use NDAs.
You can file for a registered trademark at anytime. It may be advantageous to do so before the work is completed. You can use an unregistered trademarks without registering. This differs from copyright because trademark is triggered by selling goods / services.
If things are complicated or unclear, clarify them with contracts.
This is not legal advice - if you need legal advice talk to a lawyer with expertise in this topic. The US Patent Office FAQ is a good starting point for researching question. Christopher Reid's Practical IP Law for Indie Developers 301: Plain Scary Edition (on YouTube & also the GDC Vault) gives a great overview.

So, does that mean that I can't copyright my video game before I release it? Or does that mean I can't copyright my game when it is still in its embryonic stages? (Sorry for asking so many questions. I'm still young in my development experience. Four years to be exact.)

I've added some more information to address your comment. It's okay to have questions, but there also is an expectation on Stack that there's been some attempt at research. I added a couple of links to hopefully help with that.
