Protecting New Game Content Through NDA Contract Before Sending to a Manufacturer?
I'm a new independent board game designer and would like to send sample graphics of my game content to manufacturers for quotes to produce demo sets, and to scale up to full production after I market the game.  Since it is new, the name and content do not yet have any registered trademarks.  I want to protect myself against a company taking my idea and developing it and selling a product derived from my idea without my permission before I'm ready to introduce my game to the marketplace.  Is it common (or should I consider) asking an online game manufacturer to sign a non-disclosure agreement with me first, before sharing game materials?  Are there examples of such agreements that someone can share with me?
Previous questions on related topics:

As a indie, how to protect your game?  This post does not address protecting your game idea in the pre-production stage, but does suggest that it may not be worth the risk and expense of a game producer to steal your idea.

How do I protect my rights to my game on the web?  This post does not address the possibility of using a non-disclosure agreement prior to game release.



A similar question or at least covering answer was asked a couple of days ago: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/212616/can-i-copyright-my-game-before-trademarking the comments also links a video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ePQcAjuiSEo - was there anything not covered in those two?

While many do it, not all manufacturers will agree to sign an NDA; possibly if they have never had one asked of them previously, or if they simply have a policy not to sign them. However, most established and reputable manufacturers are used to this request as part of the process and will usually comply.
You can find NDA templates on the internet, but we recommend you tailor them to your own needs. Below is a very basic example of an NDA clause:
Confidentiality Agreement
The undersigned shall maintain in confidence all materials, including without limitation artwork, game mechanics and ideas that are provided by or on behalf of the Company to the Project Owner and shall not disclose such material to anyone nor use such material for any purpose other than determining whether or not to proceed with the making of the Game.
